# ¿Como puedo construir una condición usando cadenas de caracteres?

Tags: javascript

es posible en javascript crear una condición if teniendo los siguientes datos

> dato1 = '1'; dato2 = '<'; dato3 = '6';
>
> if(dato1 dato2 dato3){  'es menor' }

y resulte algo así

> if(dato1 < dato2){  'es menor' }

lo que busco es que el condicional '<' aunque sea un string sea validado como operador lógico.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sí, pero no de forma directa. Primero tendrías que crear una cadena con el código resultante y luego ejecutarlo con la función `eval()`.

```js
dato1 = '1'; dato2 = '<'; dato3 = '6';

let code = `if(${dato1} ${dato2} ${dato3}){ console.log('es menor') }`

eval(code)
```

Answer (score 0):

También se puede lograr usando Function:

```js
 function compare(a,b,c){
        return Function('"use strict";return ' + a+b+c )();
    }
  

console.log(compare(512,"<",23))
console.log(compare(10,"<",23))
console.log(compare(5,"<",5))
```